# Including portions of MIT and BSD-licensed code in proprietary software

Tags: mit, license-notice, bsd

I'd like to include some code from MIT- and BSD-licensed libraries in a proprietary package, but for reasons of performance (and just organising the code better) would like to take portions of the code and include them interspersed within my own, rather than having them as a separable dependency.

What's the right approach to acknowledge this and incorporate the appropriate license files?

If I were including them as a separable dependency I would just have a separate folder with the library, including the license file, but that doesn't seem possible.

I was thinking of including a top-level folder named `third-party-licenses`, that would contain the library license files, along with a `README.md` file saying something like:

```
MyProductName includes code derived from Lib1, copyright Lib1Author, licensed under the MIT License.
See LIB1-LICENSE-FILE for details.

MyProductName includes code derived from Lib2, copyright Lib2Author, licensed under the BSD License.
See LIB2-LICENSE-FILE for details.
```

Does that sound like an appropriate way to handle it? Are there other solutions that would be better practice?

---

Edit This a slightly different question than is answered at [How should you put attribution into your project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-should-you-put-attribution-into-your-project) , which seems to cover the situation where a new project is a rewriting of, or substantially based on, another single project, rather than where the new project includes small portions here and there from other projects.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT The answers there are kind of helpful, but seem to be describing a situation where the new project is a rewriting of, or is substantially based on, another project - rather than where the new project includes lots of snippets here and there from other projects. If it's OK I'll hold out to see if anyone provides a clearer or more definitive opinion here. Thanks!

Comment: there is no difference between copying 10 lines or 10,000 lines. You need to give proper attribution for everything you are taking from other copyright holders, in line with the requirements of the respective licenses of the code you are taking.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT Right - and is the method I mentioned an appropriate way to do that? Or are there other solutions that would be better practice?

Comment: As described in [numerous answers to other questions here at Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attribution), the best practice is to have one file 'licenses.txt' with the applicable license language(s) and one 'notices.txt' with the attribution. Your proposal might be formally OK (fulfilling the requirements) but cumbersome for the reader and for everyone who might want to re-use your code.